# Setting up Nginx + PHP / MySQL on Debian 6 with current versions

Tags: debian, nginx

I am trying to make the switch to nginx from apache, but I am not very experienced with bash so I am having some trouble.

I am trying to install on the latest stable version of nginx, PHP 5.3.10, and MySQL 5.5 on Debian 6 squeeze.

The default repos contain outdated versions of the products, so I tried to install it all from dotdeb.org repo. The problem is that some of the products dotdeb has, so does the default debian repo and it prompts me to install the old versions the debain repo has and not the one dotdeb has. I tried to comment out the debian repos to leave me with just the dotdeb ones, but now I can not install the requirements that the various products PHP / MySQL need (since dotdeb doesn't include them in their repos).

Is there a way to specify I want to download something from a certain repo, and to install the requirements from another repo?

Comment: Please post exactly the commands you use and the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it.

Just add

```
Package: *
Pin: origin "packages.dotdeb.org"
Pin-Priority: 999
```

to

```
/etc/apt/preferences
```

This will make anything on dotdeb the highest prority

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try :

```
apt-get install package=version
```

to select the latest version of the package in the dotdeb repo. Dependencies should be correctly resolved too.